# Unity FPS on Android changes 29/59

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, settings, frame-rate

When you start the game on Android, the fps is shown at 29.59 (from a few seconds to 3-5 minutes), after which the fps evens out and becomes stable at 60 (the phone just supports 60 hertz). Also, if you minimize and reopen the game, I get 29.59 fps back (what exactly do these two numbers have to do with waiting again). Even if you disable all objects and scripts, leaving only the camera and the FPS counter, the situation remains exactly the same (even turned off the GUI itself).

Profiler shows that Semaphore.WaitForSignal is loading by 50-70%, but I still don’t understand if this is the problem and how to solve it.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIf9S.jpg

Phone: Redmi Note 7. Tested on 4 different phones (of which 3 had such a problem) and only on a more powerful one with a hertz of 120 remained stable 120. Application.targetFrameRate limit = 280;

Project settings. All static objects are set to Static. Shader: Mobile/Difuse, Mobile/. Graphics API: tried everything possible (OpenGLES 3, OpenGLES 2, Vulkan).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQwOs.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugEIw.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIVqD.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/99i2D.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/29bdU.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DKFF.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXTvs.jpg